# Execute JavaScript code after $_POST request in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, geocoding

I want to place a marker on a map with geocoding. I got a working code for that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var address = document.getElementById("address").value + ", CH";
        geocoder.geocode(
            {'address': address},
        function(results, status){          
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                    {
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        title: 'Sie suchten nach:' + ' ' + address
                    });
                }

            else if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
                window.alert = function(){}
            }

            else
            {
                alert("An unknown error occured. Refresh the page or contact the IT team! Error: '" + status + "'");
            }
    });
});
```

And I got this HTML form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Enter a zip code" style="width:250px;" onkeypress='filterTextbox(event)' />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If I hit `submit` it should send my request to the server with `$_POST` and then send me an answer. After that, I want to execute the `JavaScript` code. So I've done this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            echo "<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var address = document.getElementById('address').value + ', CH';
                geocoder.geocode(
                {'address': address},
                function(results, status){          
                    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            title: 'Sie suchten nach:' + ' ' + address
                        });
                    }

                    else if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
                        window.alert = function(){}
                    }

                    else{
                        alert('An unknown error occured. Refresh the page or contact the IT team! Error: '' + status + ''');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

It sends me an answer (the page refresh because of the `action`) but then it does not execute the `JavaScript` code. The `JavaScript` code is for placing a marker at the place of what the users typed in the textbox. And it's working fine if I execute it "normal".

Hope you know what I mean

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors

```
alert('An unknown error occured. Refresh the page or contact the IT team! Error: '' + status + ''');
```

should be

```
alert('An unknown error occured. Refresh the page or contact the IT team! Error: \'' +  status + '\'');
```

Another likely cause is that the geocoder function has not yet been initialised by the time the document is ready.

Somewhere earlier on the page you should have code that looks similar to this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}
```

You need to run your script at that point.

A way you can ensure that your script will be run is this:

```
// Where you load geocoder
var race_won = false;
var load_php_script = function() {
  race_won = true;
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  load_php_script();
}

// Replace document.ready with this:
var php_script = function() {
  // .. your old document ready code here ..
}
if (race_won) {
  php_script();
}
else {
  load_php_script = php_script;
}
```

Comment: Oh, didn't noticed that, thanks for the hint. This wasn't the error, you maybe know the error?

Comment: Maybe geocoder has not been loaded yet?
In your first script you call geocoder on a click event, but in the one loaded by php you call it in document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ajax request and run your JS code after success of this request.

You are using jQuery so you can use:

```
$('#yourform-id').on('submit', function(event) {
    $.ajax('/your/url/here', {
        type: 'post',
        data: { zipcode: $('#address').val() }
    }).done(function() {
        /* your JS code after successful request goes here */
    });

    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

**EDIT:** You can do this also without the ajax request. But the important thing is to register the `.on('submit', function(event) { /* your geocode JS code here */ event.stopPropagation(); }` event to your form so the form doesn't get sent.

The `event.stopPropagation()` stops your form from reloading the page and send the form data via HTTP. In earlier jQuery versions you returned `false` but this is deprecated now.

So add this code to the HTML file where your form is too:

```
$(function() { // on ready
    $('#yourform-id').on('submit', function(event) {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value + ', CH';
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status){          
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: 'Sie suchten nach:' + ' ' + address
                });
            } else if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
                window.alert = function(){}
            } else{
                alert('An unknown error occured. Refresh the page or contact the IT team! Error: '' + status + ''');
            }
        });

        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: I never use `ajax` before. With "/your/url/here" you mean my .php file or just the url where the .php file is executed? Is `zipcode` an ajax function?

Comment: No the `data` param is holding a JS object. And will be automatically transformed to `zipcode=value&otherparam=value2&...`. The `/your/url/here` should be replaced to the URL of your PHP script which delivers the coordinates or whatever for your request.

Comment: Yeah I've seen your edit. It doesn't place the marker. Just like before. It refresh the page (so I get an answer) but then the JavaScript code doesn't execute

Comment: Well have you given your form an id and registered the event on this? So for my example to work you have to change your form tag to `<form id="yourform-id">` to work.

Comment: Yeah I've done it but it doesnt help :/ I now copy my code in a new file and make a completely new structure, maybe I see the error then.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have included jquery in the response? Are you sure that the element id="address" exists? Does browser's developer console report some error? Use breakpoints in it and see what's going on.

Comment: When page loads, there is no error in the console but if I hit the button there appears an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'geocode' of undefined"

Comment: That probably means the geocoder object has not yet been initialised. Make sure it loads before you bind the submit handler.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you try to update google maps when you push submit button. I don't see the neccessity of the form unless you want to save the addres in your database but then you should use ajax also.
If i'm right you should have this:

Explanation: when you press submit button will not refresh anymore the page and the address from input field will be send to the `geocode` function which will make an ajax call and at succes `status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK` will execute the code from that if.

```
<div>
     <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Enter a zip code" style="width:250px;" onkeypress='filterTextbox(event)' />
      <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>


 $('#submit').click(function(){
            var address = document.getElementById('address').value + ', CH';
            geocoder.geocode(
            {'address': address},
            function(results, status){          
                if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        title: 'Sie suchten nach:' + ' ' + address
                    });

                    // save the address in database

                       $.ajax ({
                           url: "saveAddress.php",
                           data: {'address': address},
                           success: function() {  //
                                 alert("Should be saved in database");
                           }
                       });


                }

                else if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
                    window.alert = function(){}
                }

                else{
                    alert('An unknown error occured. ');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say: The form is needed because later I want to get the value of the textbox

Comment: so when you update the map on the same method you will save the address or do other things with it

Comment: Yeah I get the zip code from the textbox and then I use it for other stuff